# Polling Multiple email accounts from one app

Tags: spring, email, jakarta-mail, spring-integration

I am supposed to poll 3 email inboxes on our mail server using spring integration 
 I have three inbound email adapters doing that and each poller is handling different business logic. 
Assuming the inboxes are I1,I2 and I3 
The problem arises when , someone sends one email with the three email ids in the To address .(I1@domain.org,I2@domain.org,I3.domain.org) . The three pollers pick up the emails from each inbox  as expected.

Is there a way to determine the right 'To' address for each email poller and get the value in the mail_to header . Right now it has (I1@domain.org,I2@domain.org,I3.domain.org) in it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comment to the other answer, by "right" you mean identify which adapter the email originated at.

It's not clear why you would need this, given that each is processed by "different business logic" anyway. I can see that if the adapters feed the same logic it might be useful.

There's currently no way to have the adapter add the header itself.

You could add a `<header-enricher/>` right after each adapter to add the header to identify which adapter received the message.

**EDIT:** (for comments below).

You can't use a `<int-mail:header-enricher/>` for custom headers, but you can use a regular header-enricher:

```
<int:header-enricher ...>
   <int:header name="#{T(org.springframework.integration.mail.MailHeaders).TO}"
               value="I1@domain.org" />
   <int:header name="x-Foo" value="bar" />
   <int:header name="x-Baz" expression="payload.getHeader("x-baz") /> <!-- payload is a MimeMessage -->
</int:header-enricher>
```

The `int-mail` version is just a convenience for the built-in headers.

There's no existing "TO" header to overwrite - it's not populated by the inbound adapter.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I am required to determin which inbox an email is from and trigger different business layer services .

Comment: thanks i did try that, i have the adapter wired to a int-chain that has a header enricher. the adapters 'channel' is the input channel for this chain . Is that the right way to do it . The flow seems to stop right after the adapter. I am still trying to figure out why though!
 
  

...........   I dont think it is working as expected though!trying to figure out what is wrong right now!

Comment: Why not simply connect each adapter to the appropriate business flow for that particular inbox? Turn on DEBUG logging and follow the messages through the flow(s). If you still can't figure it out, post your configuration.

Comment: 1)Can i use the int-mail:header enricher after an inbound email adapter and overrride the int-mail:to header . 2) Is it possible to add custom header using the int-mail:header-enricher

Comment: sorry! I just saw your comment earlier.  I have 7 or 8 pollers connected to one transformer and it in turn is connected to a splitter which is connected to a file  outbound gateway .  I  took the spring integration sample and tweaked it a lot ,to my needs . I download the attachments , email body as a file and also write a metadata file (xml) and a .done file . I have another file polling app that picks these and does the neccessary business logic.

Comment: so what I basically need to do is , update/override the value in the TO header in the javamailmessage ,or add a custom header somehow . so I can access  it from within my transformer ,so I can write it  into the metadata(xml)  file that i create .This way ,I will not have to change other parts of the application .

Comment: Also , I see only 11 headers in the mailmessage .  Can i use the X-foo header .like   <int:chain id="inboundEmail-chain" input-channel="inboundEmailChannel"
  output-channel="outboundEmailChannel">
    <int-mail:header-enricher>
   <int-mail:X-foo  value="${inbox.id}" />
   </int-mail:header-enricher> 
    </int:chain>

Comment: You can't add custom headers with the mail header enricher, but you can use a regular header enricher. I edited my answer.

Comment: I tried that. I dont seem to get the headers inside the MailMessage in the transformer though. my transformer signature is List< EmailFragment> transformit(javax.mail.Message MailMessage){...} .  I changed it to List< EmailFragment> transformit(final Message<?> inputMessage) and i get a custom header in now. Thank you . I think I am good now! It would have been nicer if the inbound email adapter added a header "source_mailbox" or something ,into the javax.mail.Message payload that it sends down stream ,since its not uncommon that people will put multiple email ids in the To address :)

Comment: Feel free to open an [improvement JIRA issue](http://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) it wouldn't be too hard to add a header `mail_mailBoxURL` or similar. Even better, consider  [contributing a pull request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) for the JIRA :)

Comment: On a different note - when i start my app with multiple email pollers . only one poller seems to work  . I have a separate context file for each of the pollers .I import the context files   into a main app context file. which is loaded in the web.xml . all pollers were working when i had them defined in one app context file earlier. should i be loading them all in the web.xml rather than importing them into one context file. Is there a difference between the two .

Comment: Please don't piggy-back new issues on an existing question. Start a new one. It's also customary to "accept" an answer, to help other people searching. It makes no difference (import Vs. one file). Again, we need to see the configuration for questions like this.

Comment: Ok I will create a new issue

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "right".

There may be no address in the email header that corresponds to the primary user of the mailbox.  Or there may be more than one.

In the simple case, someone has to tell you what the primary email address is that's associated with the mailbox you're polling.  Often there's an obvious association, but not always.  If someone tells you this, you can examine the incoming messages and try to match them, but again there could be no matches.

How do you want to use this information?  That may determine whether it's appropriate to guess, to use heuristics, or to give up because you can't solve the problem.

Comment: every poller gets a javamailmessage when it reads an email from an inbox.the question was more to the Spring Integration guys to see if I could do anything like enriching the headers through the spring integration pollers with the right To address ,since the pollers are aware of which inbox they are polling

Comment: Is there a way to access the MailMessge->url->username proprerty publicly